# how to send an array in postman and receive in a correctly form in OpenApi3.0

Tags: python, postman, openapi

I'm tryng to send a array via form-data in postman and get the info in a schema using openapi3.0 in python, but I get this error in postman and honestly I do not know what I'm doing bad, any help is appreciated.
[postman_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXJE6.png)

```
    openapi: 3.0.0
      version: 0.0.1
    servers:
      - url: https://localhost:3005
    components:
      schemas:
        email:
          type: object
          properties:
            receivers:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
            header:
              type: string
            message:
              type: string
            file1:
              type: string
              format: binary
            file2:
              type: string
              format: binary
 paths:
    /api/email/{id}:
    post:
      tags:
      - email data
      summary: Send a email
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/email'
      operationId: routes.email.route_send_email
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        description: sender company ID
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: Everything is ok
        500:
          description: there was an error starting the facial recognition system
```

Comment: just see the api structure of the application also see you content-type

Comment: @sahasrara62 my bad, I'm going to add it to the code section